# What Command or Commands need to Run When I create a Plugin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I created a Plugin form Magento, I need to know what commands need to run.

Answer (score 1):

To enable module run below command:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If you have dependency injections in your module then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you have any js, css or template(html) etc then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (-f if not in production mode)
```

Comment: If you are in developer mode, there is no need to run setup:di:compile setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a plugin then you need to run following commands:

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

once you run the setup:upgrade then you can check weather your module is enabled or not.
static-content:deploy will deploy your static view files.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Assuming that the module code is already present in your file structure, either in the app/code directory or the vendor directory, you should only need to run the commands shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Plugin folder to app/code path and run the following commands

Enables specified module

```
   php bin\magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName
```

Upgrades the Magento application, DBdata, and schema

```
   php bin\magento setup:upgrade
```

To check whether plugin installed or not, check app/etc/config.php file .

the value should be 1 for that module.